# Combine timeout chaining

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-bluetooth, combine

I writing a Bluetooth LE library using combine, that I'd like to release on Github. This is my first project using combine and I'm a tittle bit overwhelmed by the syntax, because sometimes is a little bit ugly.
In these case I'm trying to add and optional timeout parameter to a function that makes a scan looking for peripheral nearby. Since it is optional the only way I've found to create a chain like this one (see the `flatMap`), but is really ugly. Is there any suggestion to improve it?

```
    /// Starts scanning for `PeripheralDiscovery`
    /// - parameter services: Services for peripheral you are looking for
    /// - parameter options: Scanning options same as  CoreBluetooth  central manager option.
    /// - parameter timeout: An optional timeout, when triggered send and error `.scanTimeout`
    /// - returns: A publisher with stream of disovered peripherals.
    public func startDiscovery(withServices services: [CBUUID]?, options: [String : Any]? = nil, timeout: TimeInterval? = nil) -> AnyPublisher<PeripheralDiscovery, LittleBluetoothError> {
        let scan = ensureBluetoothState()
        .flatMap {_ -> AnyPublisher<Void, LittleBluetoothError> in
                let just = Just(()).setFailureType(to: LittleBluetoothError.self)
                if let time = timeout {
                    return just.timeout(RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride(time), scheduler: RunLoop.current, customError: {.scanTimeout}).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                } else {
                    return just.eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
        }
        .map { (_) -> Void in
            self.cbCentral.scanForPeripherals(withServices: services, options: options)
        }
        .flatMap {
            self.centralProxy.centralDiscoveriesPublisher.setFailureType(to: LittleBluetoothError.self)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        return scan
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessarily cleaner or better, but you could set the timeout to `Double.infinity` as the default value

Comment: Your chain is also somewhat weird, with `.map` mapping to a Void followed by a `flatMap`? It's not clear what `scanForPeripherals` or `ensureBluetoothState` do, but there might not need to be this long of a chain

Comment: Why build in the timeout at all? If the caller wants a timeout, she can just say `startDiscovery(...).timeout(...)` herself.

Comment: @robmayoff sure, you are totally right!

Comment: @NewDev yes the map is useless, thanks